# Arabic text is slightly display below in text line

Tags: flutter, fonts, arabic-support, line-height

I expect line color will be all blue, because yellow is covered by text background color.
When fallback happen text line height change.

```
 Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: const Text(
                'Wi-Fi 設定 한글 العربية',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans CJK',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  height: 1.7142857142857142,
                  leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  fontFamilyFallback: [
                    'Noto Sans Arabic',
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

and this is what i get as result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97FFw.png)
In my understanding, line height is same as Line so this time will be 72px.
but line height is 77px.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIvTM.png)
Do you know how to fix this problem ?

I expect line color has only blue.

Comment: you want that the text is proportional  ?

Comment: i want fit each language baseline ands line height.